# Visual Studio 2013 won't start up

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I installed 2 versions of the free trial for Visual Studio 2013, first Professional, then Ultimate. When I try to launch the first time, it locks up and eventually gives a "not responding" message. The first time I try, it crashes the operating system with a "kernel_inpage_data_error". I'm running Windows 8.1.

I've tried multiple times to repair the install, and tried a total uninstall/reinstall. I get the same result every time.

Comment: Would you please give us more details about your system?  Why you didn't install express edition instead of trial?

Comment: What details do you need? I'm running a Lenovo Twist. I didn't do express because this is for a professional contract that I will actually be making money from, and the company I have the contract with will have to maintain when the contract is over.

Comment: Is your system 64 or 32? Did you update your. Net framework?

Comment: It is 64-bit Pro. My framework is 4.5.1, which from what I can tell is current.

Comment: I think it could be a good idea if your try to uninstall VS and all the libraries and install again and this time try to keep the log files. Because some times Kernal errors could be because of the RAM problem